# Ruby on Rails migration from Ruby 1.8.7 Rails 2.3.15 to Ruby 2 and Rails 4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

Could any one please the pros and cons to migrate from Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2.3.15 to Ruby 2 and Rails 4 also i would like to know the process to work on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too many changes are there in rails 2.X and 3.0. If you are able to do all configuration, You can..!! We had migrated one of our project recently. But make sure to migrate version wise as Abhilash explained.

[225-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/225-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-1)

[226-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/226-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-2)

[226-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/226-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-2)

[415-upgrading-to-rails-4](http://railscasts.com/episodes/415-upgrading-to-rails-4)

Below are the list of features.!!, you need to take care.

(1) Introduction of bundler (New way to manage your gem dependencies)

(2) Gemfile and Gemfile.lock (Where all your gem dependencies lies, instead of environment.rb)

(3) A new .rb file in config/ folder, named as application.rb
 (Which has everything that previously environment.rb had)

(4) Change in SQL Structure: Model.where(:activated => true)

(5) All the mailer script will now be in app/mailers folder, 
earlier we kept inside app/models.

(6) Rails3-UJS support. for links and forms to work as AJAX, 
instead of writing complex lines of code, we write :remote => true

(7) HTML 5 support.

(8) Changes in the model based validation syntax: validates :name, :presence => true

(9) Ability to install windows/ruby/jruby/development/production specific gems to Gemfile.

```
group :production do 
  gem 'will_paginate' 
end
```

All the Best.!

Comment: Pravin Mishra, You are asking me to migrate to rails 2.X to 3 then to rails 4, then what is the case for Ruby migration from 1.8.7 to 2?

Comment: You need to take care of few Syntax and new methods that's has beed added and updated, Look to these below ruby release note:

https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2010/08/18/ruby-1-9.2-released/

https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/02/24/ruby-2-0-0-p0-is-released/

https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2012/04/20/ruby-1-9-3-p194-is-released/

Comment: The same question is asked here http://www.reddit.com/r/ruby/comments/1q8p42/goin_nuclear_upgrading_from_rubyrails_1872315_to/

Comment: It's right, You can, depends your application complexity, You need to take care of Syntax and methods only, As per application code base. Rest you can use RVM.

Answer (score 4):

It is not easy to migrate Rails 2.0 to Rails 4.0. So many changes are there in Rails versions 2.0 to 3.0, such as introduction of Gemfile and removal of plugins. So while migrating from Rails 2.0 to Rails 4.0 you need to replace all the plugins that comes under vendor/plugins to gems (find the gems corresponding to the plugin). May be some plugins not available for Rails 4.0. In that case you need to replace this with another. All other plugins code need to be modified.

So you migrate Rails 2.0 to Rails 3.0 first and Rails 3 to Rails 4. Rails has lot of changes from 2.0 to 3.0. You can check the Rails casts for this here:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/225-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-1

http://railscasts.com/episodes/226-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-2.

And from Rails 3.0 to 4.0, you can migrate easily than migrating from Rails 2.0 to 3.0. Then also you have to update all the Gems versions compatible to Rails 4.0 and change the code if it needs. And in Rails 4.0 scope syntax in models, Rails find_by_name method, in routes match statement etc you have to replace with new ones. You can see the Railscasts here:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/415-upgrading-to-rails-4

http://railscasts.com/episodes/400-what-s-new-in-rails-4?view=comments.